# disappearing text effect on fixed background

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to create disappearing text effect like the text "DESTINATIONS" on this [site](http://theblondeabroad.com/destinations/). I know how to create the fixed background effect by

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

but I don't know which properties need to be added to the text. As I see the text should have `position: absolute;` but it doesn't give me an effect like on this site when we scroll and the text disappear.

[image]

Comment: `#main` is dinamically added a `z-index` value of `3` and `position:relative`. This makes it render above the container of the text. If you add a `z-index` value of `-1`, to the text container, as Johannes suggests,  you won't be able to slowly scroll the `#main` over the text, because the text will be below its parent, so it won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The text obviously has `position: fixed`, which fixes its position in relation to the viewport/window, not in relation to any other HTML element.

To make it be covered by the scrolling elements, the easiest way is to give it a negative z-index value, like `z-index: -1;` That way it will be covered by other elements which have no z-index at all.

The element with the image behind that text needs an even greater negative z-index to stay under it. And it obviously also has `position: fixed`.

(All this without looking at the code, might be slightly different, but that's the most common way to make that work this way)